# How to use multiple where clause in one sql query

Tags: sql

Hello guys i need to use mutiple where clause in one sql query as follows but it can't work please help me.

```
select (select count(total) as 'studentMarks1' from School  where total <60 ),
       (select count(total) as 'studentMarks2' from School  where total >80 ) 
from School
where Id = '8'
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rather need to use `CASE` statement like

```
select SUM(case when total < 60 then 1 else 0 end) as 'studentMarks1',
       sum(case when total > 80 then 1 else 0 end) as 'studentMarks2' 
from School
where Id = '8'
```

Comment: Thnks @Rahul it works , what i don't know is why they use `SUM` , so if i need use Sum as operator like  `select sum(total)` ' there will not be a problem in query

Comment: @user3518835, that's conditional sum and only when condition meets the sum operation will happen adding 1 to the sum which is same as performing a count operation. if it has to be sum then you can do like `select sum(case when condition then total else 0 end)`

Comment: ooh! it woks . i am sorry to as muck ,i was not familiar with `case` but it's great , so whe i want to select  all like  `select * where total >50 and where total = 40` how does this works ?

Comment: Case expression, not case statement.

Answer (score 1):

You cau usually do this with an appropriate `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN total < 60 then 1 else NULL END)
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN total > 80 then 1 else NULL END)
FROM School
WHERE ID = '8'
```